# Oracle SQL REGEXP to fetch the last numeric value in a string

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, regexp-replace

I have the below string value in a column and I need to extract the last numeric value. I have used `SUBSTR(ColumnA, -1, 1)`, but this is extracting only the last digit.

| ColumnA |
| --- |
| 12_23_AB245-F5 |
| 66_78_HJ378-G5567 |
| 55_16_GC761-B99898 |

Below is the expected result

| ColumnA |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 5567 |
| 99898 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here with the pattern `[0-9]+$`:

```sql
SELECT ColumnA, REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnA, '[0-9]+$') AS last_digits
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo